# Dlib: How to initialize an mmod_rect with its ignore flag set to 1?

Tags: c++, vector, struct, constructor, dlib

Fair warning for those that don't like answering basic questions: I haven't so much as seen C++ code in a long time.  Some of what I am asking is basic syntax stuff that I just don't know enough about the language to formulate questions about.  I don't know what to google.  Hopefully some of you can help me out in editing my question into something cohesive.

So the issue is this.  I am currently working on a project involving dlib.  In dlib, there is a struct called an mmod_rect defined [here](http://dlib.net/dlib/image_processing/full_object_detection.h.html).

```
struct mmod_rect
{
    mmod_rect() = default; 
    mmod_rect(const rectangle& r) : rect(r) {}
    mmod_rect(const rectangle& r, double score) : rect(r),detection_confidence(score) {}
    mmod_rect(const rectangle& r, double score, const std::string& label) : rect(r),detection_confidence(score), label(label) {}

    rectangle rect;
    double detection_confidence = 0;
    bool ignore = false;
    std::string label;

    operator rectangle() const { return rect; }
    bool operator == (const mmod_rect& rhs) const
    { 
        return rect == rhs.rect 
               && detection_confidence == rhs.detection_confidence
               && ignore == rhs.ignore 
               && label == rhs.label;
    }
};

inline mmod_rect ignored_mmod_rect(const rectangle& r)
{
    mmod_rect temp(r);
    temp.ignore = true;
    return temp;
}
```

If it is relevant, the documentation for rectangles is found [here](http://dlib.net/dlib/geometry/rectangle.h.html).  Basically, rectangle is a class that is initialized by passing in integers for left, top, right, and bottom.

The working code I was provided with first defines a vector of mmod_rects as follows:

```
std::vector<mmod_rect> rects;
```

Then it pushes to the vector with the line:

```
rects.push_back(rectangle(left, top, right, bottom));
```

I am confused by the above line.  Since rects is a vector of mmod_rects and NOT a vector of rects, how is it that the code gets away with calling the constructor for a rect and pushing it on to the vector.  Why doesn't this throw a compiler error?  I assume it has to do with the line in mmod_rect's struct definition, where it says:

```
mmod_rect(const rectangle& r) : rect(r) {}
```

My understanding is that this means that you can construct an mmod_rect by passing in a reference to a rectangle.  I am just confused by the syntax using the colon

```
 : rect(r) {}
```

If someone could explain what exactly this syntax does, and how the push_back operation here works, that'd be great.

Now on to the main thing I want to ask.  My goal is to populate the vector rects with mmod_rects that have their ignore flag set to 1.  How would I go about doing this?  Would the following code accomplish the goal?

```
mmod_rect r(rectangle(left, top, right, bottom));
r.ignore = 1;
rects.push_back(r);
```

is there a better way to do this using ignored_mmod_rect?  I don't fully understand what the code does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing after the colon in the constructor is a "member initializer list". See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list or search here for "c++ member initializer list."

Indeed the reason pushing a `rectangle` onto a `std::vector` of `mmod_rect` is because `mmod_rect` can be constructed from a `rectangle`. C++ allows one level of implicit constructor to be used. A constructor can be marked `explicit` to prevent it from being used automatically in such situations.

In effect `rectangle` and `mmod_rect` are "value" types. This means you can treat them as if they were e.g. numbers. (Often more sophisticated types have to be treated as if they share substructure or cannot be copied easily, etc.) The `ignored_mmod_rect` function simply transforms one value to another. This you can write something like:

```
rects.push_back(ignored_mmod_rect(rectangle(left, top, right, bottom));
```

In a top-notch API design today, this would likely be done via a method on `mmod_rect` and there would be an initializer-list based constructor for `rectangle` so one could just write `{left, top, right, bottom}` instead of `rectangle(left, top, right, bottom)`.

Comment: Thanks for breaking down some of the terminology.  Looking at the documentation for member initializer lists was helpful in understanding what is going on.